# PowerShell: unable to loop through files located in other directory than the script file itself

Tags: xml, windows, powershell-5.0

I am trying to test if I can loop through .xml files located in a different directory than the .ps1 script itself:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\ps_scripts\configs' 

foreach ($file in $files) {
    $xml = [xml](Get-Content $file.FullName)
    Write-Host $xml
}
```

When I run the above script, I get several empty lines as the output. I also tried to add `-Recurse` parameter in the first line, but the problem persists.
If I type in the PowerShell terminal `$files = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\ps_scripts\configs'`, then the $files variable returns a list of files as I expect:

```
PS C:\ps_scripts> $files = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\ps_scripts\configs'
PS C:\ps_scripts> $files


    Directory: C:\ps_scripts\configs


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        12/2/2019   9:09 AM           3820 ams_merge_ab.xml
-a----        12/2/2019   9:09 AM           3894 ams_merge_ba.xml
-a----        12/2/2019   9:09 AM           4451 ams_merge_cg.xml
-a----        2/10/2020  12:28 PM           4029 ams_merge_de.xml
-a----        12/3/2019   3:22 PM           4222 ams_merge_so.xml
```

If `$files` actually do contain the list of files in the directory, then why the `foreach` block fails to return anything?

Answer (score 2):

$files = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C\ps_scripts\configs'
$files  = $files.FullName

foreach ($file in $files) {  Write-Host $file }

Comment: Thanks, now I can iterate through files alright. But what if I want to loop through all XML files AND extract text from certain XML tags? I tried to modify 'Write-Host' line like this and it doesn't work --> "Write-Host [xml](Get-Content $file.process.config.firstDate)"

Answer (score 1):

Given the code in my original post, I was using `Write-Host $xml` in order to check if XML filenames' values are returned. As mentioned, I only got empty lines as the output.
But when I modify this line like this -> `Write-Host $xml.'process-config'.firstDate --- $file`, then I get the value stored between `<firstDate>` tags of each XML file:

```
2019-12-02 --- ams_merge_ab.xml
2019-12-02 --- ams_merge_ba.xml
2019-12-02 --- ams_merge_cg.xml
2020-01-20 --- ams_merge_de.xml
2019-12-02 --- ams_merge_so.xml
```

So I was thinking that there was something wrong with my looping method but it works if I just add XML tag names separated by dot right after `$xml` variable